# Browser compatibility for -webkit-scrollbar (CSS)

Tags: css, webkit, scrollbar

I want to customise the scroll bar.

According to this: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-styling-scrollbars-to-match-your-ui-design--webdesign-9430

you can do it using -webkit-scrollbar. However I cannot seem to find anywhere which browsers support this feature including caniuse.com.

Can someone please tell me where I can find out which browsers support this feature!

As it says -webkit- I assume it works on safari and chrome. But even then which "versions" of these browsers does this work on? What about andriod/ chrome mobile browsers .

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can for [IE and Webkit browsers](http://codemug.com/html/custom-scrollbars-using-css/) but Firefox would require a JS solution - and if you bother to do it in JS, it doesn't really need you to do it in CSS as well.

[An example of a JS scrollbar jQuery plugin.](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/)

Edit: Mobile browser - you apparently can style these but I haven't noticed them styled at all, nor did I even know my phone had scrollbars until I just checked. [This plugin](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/) seems to be able to style them.